# Typeahead.js - Bind this on selected event

Tags: vuejs2, typeahead.js

I am making a Vue app where I implement typeahead.js
I would like to bind the selected value to my model through the this.model = selectedItem on the .on(« typeahead :selected, function()) but when  i do that the this is referencing the input where i have my typeahead input.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you question is confusing

Comment: What do you find confusing in here ?

Comment: can you provide more i.e code if possible